# How to Create a Slicer that uses dates and that only contains YTD Months dynamically by current date in PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, daxstudio

Trying to create a slicer that when clicked only the months YTD, specifically up the the last month of current.

Such as slicer box clicked: (Say current month is August) then Months "Jan","Feb",..."July" would only display to click.

I've tried several things, my last attempt was to create a Dax table with dates and try to do a switch:

```
Dates = 
var CurrentMonthInt = month(TODAY())
var monthis8 = "Jan" + "Feb" + "March" + "April" + "May" + "June" + "July"
VAR BaseTable = 
CALENDAR(
    DATE( YEAR ( MIN(Reporting[InvoiceDate])),01,01),
    DATE( YEAR ( MAX(Reporting[InvoiceDate])),12,31)
)
RETURN
 ADDCOLUMNS(
     BaseTable,
     "Year", YEAR([Date]),
     "Month", FORMAT([Date],"mm"),
     "Year Month", FORMAT([Date],"YYYY MM"),
     "Month YTD",   SWITCH(TRUE(), 
    CurrentMonthInt = 1, "Jan",
    CurrentMonthInt = 8,  monthis8,
    "testing"
    )
 )

this returns a variant data type and will not work. I am thinking this is trying to add them all up on the same row.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hello Please test this and let me know if It solves your problem.

```
Dates =
VAR CurrentMonthInt =
    MONTH ( TODAY () )
VAR BaseTable =
    CALENDAR (
        DATE ( YEAR ( MIN ( Reporting[InvoiceDate] ) ), 01, 01 ),
        DATE ( YEAR ( MAX ( Reporting[InvoiceDate] ) ), 12, 31 )
    )
RETURN
    FILTER (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            BaseTable,
            "Year", YEAR ( [Date] ),
            "Month", MONTH ( [Date] ),
            "Year Month", FORMAT ( [Date], "YYYY MM" )
        ),
        [Month] <= CurrentMonthInt - 1
    )
```

Note: I haven't tested it.

Comment: it says "DAX comparison operations do not support comparing values of type Text with values of type Integer. Consider using the VALUE or FORMAT function to convert one of the values."

Comment: Please check your InvoiceDate column on Reporting table. It must be date data type, not text/string. If It is text/string, Change it to date or date time data type.

Comment: it is a date time data type

Comment: okay, I found it. It is the [Month] column. We used format function, and it returns text. I am updating the code now. Please test it after update.

Comment: Now please test it. I updated the code.

Comment: Boom, you are the man!

Comment: Wow! I Great news. I am happy to hear it. Stay safe!